# My Gravitational Pull Algorithm behaves Oddly in Certain Situations

Tags: c++, physics

While trying to create my own physics engine (don't try persuading me not to), I decided to create a class for each pixel, called `Particle`, this system has an x and a y, and a x and y velocity, as shown below. Unfortunately, the code for `calculateGravitationalVelocity` doesn't abide by the laws of physics in certain situations. For example, if the x of the particle and the x of the other particle is the same, the particle will fall towards the object realistically, but when the particle gets too close, it pings off towards the positive x. I am only going to include the class source code, but I can include the source code of the other file, though it is partly written in SFML

`Particle.cpp:`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

class Particle
{
    private:
        //Coords:
        double x, y;
        //Velocities:
        double xVelocity = 0;
        double yVelocity = 0;
        //Material:
        std::string material = "Generic";
        //Mass:
        double mass = 0;
    public:
        //Coords:
        void setCoords(double, double);
        float getCoords(char);
        //Velocities:
        void giveVelocity(char, float);
        void setVelocity(char, float);
        float getVelocity(char);
        //Gravitational Velocity:
        void calculateGravitationalVelocity(Particle);
        //Material:
        void setMaterial(std::string);
        std::string getMaterial();
        //Mass:
        void setMass(double);
        double getMass();
        //Update:
        void update();
};

//Coords:
void Particle::setCoords(double newX, double newY)
{
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
}
float Particle::getCoords(char axis)
{
    if (axis == 'x')
    {
        //return floor(x);
        return x;
    }
    else if (axis == 'y')
    {
        //return floor(y);
        return y;
    }
}

//Velocities:
void Particle::giveVelocity(char axis, float addedVelocity)
{
    if (axis == 'x') {xVelocity = xVelocity + addedVelocity;}
    else if (axis == 'y') {yVelocity = yVelocity + addedVelocity;}
}
void Particle::setVelocity(char axis, float newVelocity)
{
    if (axis == 'x') {xVelocity = newVelocity;}
    else if (axis == 'y') {yVelocity = newVelocity;}
}
float Particle::getVelocity(char axis)
{
    if (axis == 'x') {return xVelocity;}//floor(xVelocity);}
    else if (axis == 'y') {return xVelocity;}//floor(yVelocity);}
}

//Gravitational Velocity (Where the problems probably are):
void Particle::calculateGravitationalVelocity(Particle distantParticle)
{
    //Physics constants:
    const double pi = 3.14159265359; //Pi
    const double G = 0.00000000006673; //Gravitational Constant (or Big G)

    //Big Triangle Trigonometry:
    //Get coords of moving particle:
    double x1 = x;
    double y1 = y;
    //Get coords of particle with gravity:
    double x2 = distantParticle.getCoords('x');
    double y2 = distantParticle.getCoords('y');
    if (x1 != x2)
    {
        //Work out the angle:
        double A = atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * 180 / pi;
        //Remove the minus sign:
        A = fabs(A);

        //Small Triangle Trigonometry:
        //Work out the hypotenuse of the big triangle:
        double hyp = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
        //Work out the gravitational field (hyp of small triangle):
        long double gravitationalField = G * (distantParticle.getMass() / pow(hyp, 2));
        //For testing purposes:
        //std::cout << "X: " << (cos(A) * gravitationalField) / 1000 << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "Y: " << (sin(A) * gravitationalField) / 1000 << std::endl;
        //Work out the X velocity:
        xVelocity = xVelocity + (cos(A) * gravitationalField) / 1000;
        //Work out the Y velocity:
        yVelocity = yVelocity + (sin(A) * gravitationalField) / 1000;
    }
    else
    {
        //Work out the hypotenuse of the big triangle:
        double hyp = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
        //Work out the gravitational field (hyp of small triangle):
        long double gravitationalField = G * (distantParticle.getMass() / pow(hyp, 2));

        yVelocity = yVelocity + gravitationalField / 1000;
    }
}

//Material:
void Particle::setMaterial(std::string newMaterialType)
{
    material = newMaterialType;
}
std::string Particle::getMaterial()
{
    return material;
}

//Mass:
void Particle::setMass(double newMass)
{
    mass = newMass;
}
double Particle::getMass()
{
    return mass;
}

//Update:
void Particle::update()
{
    x = x + xVelocity;
    y = y + yVelocity;
}
```

I am sorry for the very open question, and it probably goes against the rules somewhere, but I couldn't find it. The code for working out mostly uses a two triangles to make a x and y velocity. Here is an image of what I was hoping the code would do as a triangle (sorry it doesn't look great, but I like using a whiteboard):
[image: Triangle Diagram]

Comment: Ignore the 45 degrees bit on the diagram, That was from where I was testing whether or not the triangle would work, and I forgot to rub it out with the other substituted values

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but I'll make a bet that it has something to do with floating point inaccuracy or roundoff.

Comment: I expect your error is in the `calculateGravitationalVelocity()` function. As the radius approaches zero, the gravitational force goes to infinity. If this is the case, you should choose some small radius `r0` and make the gravitational force is constant below this radius.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I have been having lots of problems with floats and doubles with coordinate systems and such

Comment: @eigenchris I will add a `r0` variable because that sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately that is only fixes one problem I am having with the simulation. But it is something I probably wouldn't have thought of myself

Comment: @Ben Can I ask that you edit your post to include the `calculateGravitationalVelocity()` and `update()` functions? They play a crucial role in the behaviour of the particle and it's hard to guess what's wrong without it.

Comment: @eigenchris It is there isn't it? Unless I improperly explained it. If I did, then it is the function below `float Particle::getVelocity(char axis)` and has one argument which is `Particle distantParticle`.

Comment: @Ben Pardon me--I didn't see it. I'll post an answer with my thoughts.

Comment: In any case the atan() call is problematic, check out the atan2() function instead, it probably does what you need and handles corner cases (where you currently divide by zero) much better. Further, you pass an angle in degrees to sin(), which is wrong. Stay with radians, except perhaps for UI purposes.

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but I just wanted to point out that `Particle::getCoords(char axis)` runs the risk of not returning a value if you pass something other than `'x'` or `'y'`. I believe most good compilers will raise a warning about this, but I just wanted to toss it out there. You might want to add an else statement with something like `cout << "Particle::getCoords() called with invalid parameter." << endl;` and then return some float from it. Returning the float will satisfy compiler warnings and the cout will let you know that you called it somewhere with a bad parameter.

Comment: Good point, @SpencerDoak, but it's probably better to throw an exception in those cases. Another way to avoid this is to use a datatype (e.g. called vector, not to be confused with std::vector) for the whole position and velocity, so you don't have to request each axis separately. Less (conditionally executed) code, less complexity, less erroneous, better performance.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was considering adding a vector, but I just couldn't figure out how to do it, so I figured "Hey I'm the only one making the program, so I'll most likely know how to use the functions". But if you have time you could tell me how (or just send me a link how to do it).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, yes, that's probably a much better solution. I'm used to programming in C, so typically I think about solutions in C rather than C++ ;) Anyway, thank you for pointing out a better solution to that.

Comment: `struct vector { double x; double y;};` -- it's as simple as that. You can spice this up by providing a constructor taking two doubles (or using C++11), overloaded operators to e.g. add, substract and scalar-multiply.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you! This makes lots of my code a lot easier to use and look at, especially with `Particle.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform any trigonometric calculation.

```
    ...

    //Get coords of particle with gravity:
    double x2 = distantParticle.getCoords('x');
    double y2 = distantParticle.getCoords('y');

    // Get difference vector
    double rx = x1 - x2;
    double ry = y1 - y2;

    // square of distance
    double r2 = rx * rx + ry * ry;
    // distance
    double r = sqrt (r2);

    if (r != 0) {
        // normalize difference vector
        double ux = rx / r;
        double uy = ry / r;

        // acceleration of gravity
        double a = - G * distantParticle.getMass() / r2;

        xVelocity += a * ux / 1000;
        yVelocity += a * uy / 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your formulas for updating the velocity work? I feel like you might need to use trigonometry to get them right. Also, the acceleration formula would require multiplication by `mass`. The way you calculate and use `dist2` will be better for performance, though. :)

Comment: This is ingenious! I think this is a great example of how stupid I am, and how much I over think some of my solutions.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use the square root of `dist2`? The Pythagorean Theorem is `c^2 = a^2 + b^2` (*where `a^2 + b^2` is `(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2`*). So really `trueDistance^2 = dist2`; thus, `trueDistance = SquareRoot(dist2)`. Please let me know if I'm incorrect about this.

Comment: @SpencerDoak I think there needs to be a `sqrt()`, unless it is actually supposed to be like that, which I doubt. But I'll wait for an answer from Antoine before doing anything

Comment: You are right, I forgot to normalize the difference vector. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @AntoineMathys I see my comment about the mass is incorrect. The gravitational field is being used, not the force. I would go with this answer.